# Linq Lambda join breaks when joining a table

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, join, lambda

I am fairly new to lambda. I am trying to create a join that pulls products from my db and joins a table of authors. But some products from my db doesn't have authors such as product packages. Because of this, the query doesn't pull those records.

Is there a way to pull records of all products that either have or don't have authors in linq lambda. Similar to inner joins or right joins? Here my db/query:

**DATABASE**

*Products*

```
+-----------------------------------------+--------+----+---------+
|                FullName                 | TypeId | Id |   Sku   |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+----+---------+
| The Matrix                              |      1 | 23 | MAT     |
| Lord Of The Rings                       |      1 | 22 | LOTR    |
| Package: Lord of the rings & The Matrix |      2 | 33 | LOTRMAT |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+----+---------+
```

*AuthorAssignments*

```
+--------+----+----------+
| TypeId | Id | AuthorId |
+--------+----+----------+
|      1 | 23 |        1 |
|      1 | 22 |        2 |
+--------+----+----------+
```

*Authors*

```
+----------+------------------+
| AuthorId |      Author      |
+----------+------------------+
|        1 | The Wachowskis   |
|        2 | J. R. R. Tolkien |
+----------+------------------+
```

**QUERY**

```
        var allitems = _contentService.Products.Select(
            x => new {x.FullName, x.TypeId, x.Id, x.Sku})
            .Join(
                _contentService.AuthorAssignments,
                x => new {x.TypeId, x.Id},
                y => new {y.TypeId, y.Id},
                (x, y) =>
                    new
                    {
                        x.Sku,
                        x.FullName,
                        x.Id,
                        x.TypeId,
                        y.AuthorId
                    })
            .Join(
                _contentService.Authors,
                authId => authId.AuthorId ,
                auth => auth.Id,
                (authId, auth) =>
                    new
                    {
                        authId.Sku,
                        authId.FullName,
                        authId.Id,
                        authId.TypeId,
                        authId.Image,
                        auth.Author
                    });
```

This gives me a result like this:

```
+-------------------+--------+----+------+------------------+
|     FullName      | TypeId | Id | Sku  |      Author      |
+-------------------+--------+----+------+------------------+
| The Matrix        |      1 | 23 | MAT  | The Wachowskis   |
| Lord Of The Rings |      1 | 22 | LOTR | J. R. R. Tolkien |
+-------------------+--------+----+------+------------------+
```

when this is what i am trying to accomplish

```
+-----------------------------------------+----------+----+---------+------------------+
|                FullName                 |   TypeId | Id |   Sku   |      Author      |
+-----------------------------------------+----------+----+---------+------------------+
| The Matrix                              |        1 | 23 | MAT     | The Wachowskis   |
| Lord Of The Rings                       |        1 | 22 | LOTR    | J. R. R. Tolkien |
| Package: Lord of the rings & The Matrix |        2 | 33 | LOTRMAT | null             |
+-----------------------------------------+----------+----+---------+------------------+
```

Looks like that since the package doesnt contain 1 author record it just ignored it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, i forgot to mention that i am using NHibernate. Therefore groupjoins are not implemented :(

Comment: You definitely need left outer joins, but frankly it's hard to work with joins and method syntax. If you used query syntax, the change would be trivial.

Comment: So the question is, do you want a working query or you insist on method syntax (what you call lambda)?

Comment: yeah i'd like to stay in Lambda Expressions only.

Comment: Then look at the `GroupJoin`, `SelectMany` and `DefaultIfEmpty` methods. I doubt someone here will do that tough conversion for you. Good luck.

Comment: You didn't say if you were using EntityFramework or not, but assuming that you are, you should be setting up [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) in your model, and then this would be trivial.  Also, remove the id field from AuthorAssignments table.  It isn't needed and will only cause you issues.  With navigation properties, your query becomes `var allitems=_db.Products.Include(p=>p.Authors);` (yes, all 29 lines of your code replaced with just that snippet!)

Comment: @NeoSketo You may want to take a look into [QueryOver](http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/03/12/queryover-series-part-1-why-queryover/) which deals with LINQ to NHibernate's inability with left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query in *<del>lambda expression</del>* method syntax :

```
var allitems = _contentService.Products
    .Select(x => new {x.FullName, x.TypeId, x.Id, x.Sku})
    .GroupJoin(_contentService.AuthorAssignments,
        p => p.Id,
        aa => aa.Id,
        (p, aa) => new 
        { 
            p.Sku, 
            p.FullName, 
            p.Id, 
            p.TypeId, 
            AuthorId = aa.Select(x => x.AuthorId).FirstOrDefault()
        })
    .GroupJoin(_contentService.Authors,
        p => p.AuthorId,
        a => a.Id,
        (p, a) => new 
        { 
            p.FullName, 
            p.TypeId, 
            p.Id,
            p.Sku, 
            Author = a.Select(x => x.Author).FirstOrDefault()
        });
```

Output :

```
+--------------------------------+--------+----+---------+------------------+
|            FULLNAME            | TYPEID | ID |   SKU   |      AUTHOR      |
+--------------------------------+--------+----+---------+------------------+
|                                |        |    |         |                  |
| The Matrix                     | 1      | 23 | MAT     | The Wachowskis   |
|                                |        |    |         |                  |
| Lord Of The Rings              | 1      | 22 | LOTR    | J. R. R. Tolkien |
|                                |        |    |         |                  |
| Package: Lord of the rings & T | 2      | 33 | LOTRMAT | null             |
| he Matrix                      |        |    |         |                  |
+--------------------------------+--------+----+---------+------------------+
```